# get data from a linked server using a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server, openquery

In my DB  is a table TodayID a table contains more 400000 rows, I'm looking for a way / example to load data into DB MSSQL from a linked server using a loop While,With for each ID. 
I used IN but got an error "openquery more than 8000 characters" using EXEC AT, tuning RPC, RPC out did not solve the problem.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ID  VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @resTable TABLE(ID VARCHAR(50), NAME VARCHAR(100), DTIME DATETIME, FIELD VARCHAR(100))
SET @ID = (STUFF((SELECT ',' + '''''' + [ID] + '''''' FROM [TodayID] FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') )  
Print @ID
SET @SQL='SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(RemoteServer, ''SELECT ID, NAME, DTIME, FIELD FROM AUDIT WHERE ID IN (' + @ID + ')  '')'
Print @SQL
INSERT INTO @resTable EXEC (@SQL)
select * from @resTable
```

Comment: Why would you want to use a `WHILE` in the first place?

Comment: You could just do a 4-part name and do a single insert into local select * from <4-part-table-name> without any of this, no?

Answer (score 0):

The following query will help you if you want to read table rows through the **WHILE loop** . However ID columns' values must be in the ordered.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ID  VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Counter AS INT
DECLARE @MaxCounter AS INT

DECLARE @resTable TABLE(ID VARCHAR(50), NAME VARCHAR(100), DTIME DATETIME, FIELD VARCHAR(100))
--SET @ID = (STUFF((SELECT ',' + '''''' + [ID] + '''''' FROM [TodayID] FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'') )  

SELECT @Counter = MIN(ID) FROM [TodayID]
SELECT @MaxCounter=MAX(ID) FROM [TodayID]

WHILE(@Counter IS NOT NULL
      AND @Counter <= @MaxCounter)

      BEGIN
SET @SQL='SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(RemoteServer, ''SELECT ID, NAME, DTIME, FIELD FROM AUDIT WHERE ID IN (' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Counter) + ')  '
Print @SQL
INSERT INTO @resTable EXEC (@SQL)
SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1        --According to your id gap
END
select * from @resTable
```